# Как правильно сделать проверку на наличие русских символов в строке?

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите  , как правильно сделать проверку символов в строке ?

вот код который запрещает вводить русские символы в инпут:

```
myinput.oninput = function() {
  var srint = $("#myinput").val().replace(/[а-яА-ЯЁё-і]/g, ''); 
  srint.replace(/[а-яА-ЯЁё-і]/g, '');
  $("#myinput").val(srint);
};
```

Нужно , чтоб когда пользователь вводил русские символы срабатывала alert("введите латинские символы")

Подскажите как сделать такую проверку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Раз уж вы используете jQuery, так используйте и события

```
$("#myinput").on('keydown', function(e) {
   var regexp = /[а-яё]/i;
   if(regexp.test(this.val())) {
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("введите латинские символы");
       return false;
   }
   ...
});
```

### Дополнение

Как правильно заметил @Qwertiy лучше проверят не на присутствие запрещенных символов, а на наличие только разрешенных. Например только латиница + пробелы

```
$("#myinput").on('keydown', function(e) {
   var regexp = /^[a-z\s]+$/i;
   if(!regexp.test(this.val())) {
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("введите только латинские символы или пробелы");
       return false;
   }
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно проверять код символа в Unicode и определять входит ли он в диапазон допустимых.

- Коды от `48 до 57` - это цифры.
- Коды от `64-90` - латинские заглавные буквы от `'A'` до `'Z'`
- Коды от `97-122` - латинские строчные буквы от `'a'` до `'z'`

Промежутки между этими диапазонами содержат технические символы и знаки типа !@#$%^&*.

Коды выше 122 содержат алфавиты других культур в том числе и кириллицу (1040-1103).

Если вы допускаете ввод технических символов, то можно просто проверять что код символа меньше 122:

```
function checkInput(event) {
    var x = event.charCode;
    if(x>122)  //символ 122 это латинская 'z'
    {
      alert("Некорректный ввод");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Надо не запрещать, а разрешать. В юникоде всегда найдётся алфавит, который те не хочешь увидеть, раз уж русские буквы не подходят.

Ну и используй флаг игнорирования регистра.